# Change background color of an anchor tag when clicked, which is inside listview, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview, visual-studio-2013, webforms, anchor

I have a master page in which i have a listview which contains anchor tags.

**The problem is that I want to set the BackgroundColor only of the clicked anchor tag. The others should be default**

I am populating the data from database for the anchor tags.

**MasterPage.aspx**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Report</title>
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="smartpaginator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="smartpaginator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datepicker.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nice-menu.css" />

<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
       /* padding: 20px;*/
    }
    #wrapper
    {
       /* margin: auto; */
        width: 800px;
    }
    .contents
    {
        width: 91%; /*height: 150px;*/
        margin: 0;
    }
    .contents > p
    {
        padding: 8px;
    }
    .table
    {
        width: 100%;
        border-right: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    }
    .table th, .table td
    {
        width: 16%;
        height: 20px;
        padding: 4px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .table th
    {
        border-left: solid 1px #FFFFFF; 
        border-top: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:small;
    }
    .table td
    {
        border-left: solid 1px #5f9000;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #5f9000;
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:small;
        background-color:White;
    }
    .header
    {
        background-color: #2758A4; 
        color: White;
    }
    #divs
    {
        margin: 0;
        height: 200px;
        font: verdana;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: White;
    }
    #divs > div
    {
        width: 98%;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    #divs > div p
    {
        width: 95%;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    ul.tab
    {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul.tab li
    {
        display: inline;
        padding: 10px;
        color: White;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:small;
    }

    #container
    {
        width: 100%;
        border: solid 1px red;
    }
.style3 {font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: small; }
</style>
```

```
<body bgcolor="#DFDFDF">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  >
</table>
<table><!-- Body table start-->
<tr>
    <td valign="top" ><!--Left panel start -->
            <table border="0" width="15%" align="left" id="myTable"><!-- Left Panel table start -->
             <tr valign="top">
             <td>
            <div class = "container" style = "">
             <ul class = "nice1-menu" >
              <li><a style="background: rgb(39,88,164)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reports </a></li>          
             </ul>

             <ul class = "nice-menu" runat="server" id="ulmenu">

                 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" class="nice-menu" 
                     onselectedindexchanged="Page_Load">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <ul class="nice-menu">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />    
                        </ul>                
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li class="lightblue">
                            <a id="annexurelink" href='<%# Eval("Annexure_name")%>.aspx'>
                            <%# Eval("Annexure_name")%></a>                         
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <p>Nothing here.</p>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate> 
                  </asp:ListView>

             </ul>

           </div>                    
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table><!-- Left Panel table end -->
     </td><!--Left panel end -->
     <td valign="top"><!--Data panel start -->
        <table width="85%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><!-- data table start font-size:24px;  -->

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="green-contents" class="contents" style="border: solid 1px #2758A4;" ><!--   -->
                <!--wrapper table end -->
                <div id="green" style="margin: auto;">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>  
            </div>  

        </div>  
        </table><!-- data table end -->

    </td><!--Data panel end -->
</tr>
</table><!-- Body table start-->

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**MasterPage CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
    cnn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=3ALT15B0057; Initial Catalog=Practice; Integrated Security=true");
    SqlDataAdapter parentNode = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Annexure_list order by Annexure_name asc", cnn);
    SqlCommandBuilder cmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(parentNode);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    parentNode.Fill(ds, "Annexure_list");

    this.ListView1.DataSource = ds;
    this.ListView1.DataBind();    
}
}
```

**And The CSS File**
nice-menu.css

```
      * { margin:0; padding: 0;}  

      body {
        font-family: Helvetica, Verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        /*background: rgb(42,32,30);*/
      }

      div.container {
        width: 150px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0px; 
        background: rgb(39,88,164);
      }

      div.header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 12px;
        background: rgb(78,92,127);
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      div.header p {
        padding: 0 10px; 
      }

      div.header a {
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
      }



/*------------- Nice 1 Menu -------------*/

ul.nice1-menu li {
width: 5px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 20px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin-top: 3px;
background: transparent;
width: 5px;
}

ul.nice1-menu a {
width: 130px; 
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
/*text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #333;*/
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
padding: 5px 0px;
padding-left: 20px; 
}



/*------------- Nice Menu -------------*/

ul.nice-menu {
list-style: none;
/*margin-top: 30px;*/
width: 150px;
}

ul.nice-menu li {
width: 5px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 20px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin-top: 3px;
background: transparent;
width: 5px;
}

ul.nice-menu.tight li {
margin-top: 0 !important;
}

ul.nice-menu a {
width: 130px; 
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
/*text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #333;*/
font-weight: bold;
 position: absolute;
padding: 5px 0px;
padding-left: 20px; 
}

ul.nice-menu li.lightblue {
background: rgb(199,230,255) !important;
}


ul.nice-menu li:hover {
width: 150px; 
padding-left: auto;
-moz-animation-name: expand;
-moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-name: expand;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 }
```

Is there any function to do so or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it manually.
First, prepare a css class for your 'active' anchor, for instance:

```
.current {
    background-color: green
}
```

Then, check the current url and if matches any of your anchors href, add that class to it. You can do this server side, or client side.

If you do it server side, you could add a method in your masterpage's code behind (or in a separated .cs file) which get href as parameter and compare it to current location.

```
protected bool MatchesToCurrentLocation(string href) 
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath.ToLower().Contains(href.ToLower());
}
```

Then, in your masterpage ListView:

```
....
<ItemTemplate>
    <li class="lightblue <%# MatchesToCurrentLocation(Eval("Annexure_name") + ".aspx") ? "current" : "" %>">
        <a id="annexurelink" href='<%# Eval("Annexure_name")%>.aspx'>
            <%# Eval("Annexure_name")%>
        </a>                         
    </li>
</ItemTemplate>
...
```

Comment: Hi @zed,
It worked like Charm!!
Just had to add

`ul.nice-menu li.lightblue.current a {
    background: rgb(199,230,255);
}`


in css file

Comment: Great! I added the class to the `li` because I'm used to; but instead you could have add it to `a` as well.

Comment: Thank you @zed! My client was more than happy to see it working.